# Should this question about where to get KPI's be reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This question, https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/where-to-get-benchmark-data-for-key-performance-indicators-in-payroll-management, was closed as NARQ for lack of detail. We left some helpful comments, and the op edited it with some more details.

I could see arguments for and against reopening.  Pretty much, he added *why* he needs the data, but I'm not quite convinced the question is a good fit.  What do you think?

I was also thinking of editing the question to ask "how can we use KPI's to effectively evaluate our performance in payroll and HR management". Would this be an improvement? Why or why not?

Comment: I'm not sure that the question is answerable in its current format. I've never heard of a company publishing the information he is seeking. Who knows though, I could be wrong.

Comment: Neither have I, @aclear16. My plan is to leave it be, unless someone can either substantially improve it or make a case for it, or 5 people vote to reopen.

Comment: There are companies that collect and sell this kind of benchmark data. But I believe they can be found using Google and any answer from the community would be a list of providers.